# how to use the color black on an alpha texture?

Tags: node-editor, transparency, texture-painting

What do I when I have a model that I am painting on, the texture has an alpha layer, and I want to do something like paint the color black over some other color on that texture. when I do this of course the color black just ends up making any other color on the texture invisible. So is there way to paint on an alpha texture with the color black and have it show up instead of alpha things out? I'm trying to do this using nodes in blender 2.82.

Comment: Did you use a Transparent BSDF and a Mix Shader for the material?

Comment: no but I will try that now, thanks for asking

Comment: Ok, while i was trying out your suggestion, i found the reason it wasn't showing up while i painted on it was because  I needed to also change the objects blend mode to alpha blend instead of Opaque. this seems to have solved my problem. I think it did anyway, ill have to mess around, for a minute to see if it really does what I  wanted it to do

Comment: Hi Taylor, welcome to blender.se. If you think you have found a solution, I'd be happy if you added an answer to it in the answer box below. It is quite common to answer your own questions and would help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

in the end, i got it to show by turning the blend mode in the materials settings to alpha blend, then i could see the color black as i painting on the model.